# MLE of normal$(\mu,1)$ where samples are only positive or negative

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood

suppose we had $n$ iid observations from $N(\mu, 1),$ but the values of these observations are masked and we are only allowed to see whether each $x_i$ are positive or negative. discuss maximum likelihood estimation of $\mu.$

Without restriction, MLE of $\mu$ is $\overline X.$ I think that with the observations given, I can only estimate sign of $\mu$ (using majority signs from the samples?). But I doubt that we'll be able to estimate $\mu$ itself. Please give some hint if there's a way to estimate $\mu.$

Comment: Let the normal variable be latent and consider the probability of getting a positive. I think a probit model with only a constant in the linear  index.

Comment: Did you try to write down the likelihood ?

Comment: This is effectively just a transformation of a binomial MLE.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/407344/119261

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You observe $\text{“}{+}\text{''}$ with probability $p=\Phi\left( \dfrac{0 - \mu} 1 \right)$ and $\text{“}{-}\text{''}$ with probability $1-p=1-\Phi\left( \dfrac{0-\mu}1 \right),$ where $\Phi$ is the c.d.f. of the standard normal distribution. Let $y$ be the number of $\text{“}{+}\text{''s}$ you observe, so that $n-y$ is the number of $\text{“}{-}\text{''s}.$ Then you have the likelihood function
$$
L(p) = \binom n y p^n (1-p)^{n-y}.
$$
The value of $p$ that maximizes that is $\widehat{p\,} =y/n.$ By equivariance of MLEs, the value of $\mu$ that you seek satisfies
$$
\widehat{p\,} = \Phi\left( -\widehat\mu \right).
$$
So
$$
\widehat\mu = -\Phi^{-1}\left( \frac y n \right).
$$
And to be more fastidious, you shouldn't be calling the observations "samples"; rather they are the $n$ observations within your (one) sample.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. thank you!