# MLE of mean of normal distribution using the number of observations above zero

Tags: maximum-likelihood

Suppose we have n random variables dstributed iid by a N(mu, sigma) where sigma is known. What would be the MLE for mu if we only counted the number of observations above 0?

Comment: Do you mean something like $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma)$ and $Y = (X\vert X>0)$?

Comment: Think binomial. Similar: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/431828/119261.