# Find the MLE of $\hat{\gamma}$ of $\gamma$ based on $X_1, ... , X_n$

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, confidence-interval, maximum-likelihood, likelihood

new user here self-studying some mathematical statistics.

I have a problem that has been tripping me up for a few days now. The problem is as follows:

For $1 \leq i \leq n$ and letting $X_1, ... , X_n$ be a random sample from a $N(\phi, 1)$ density, we define $Y_i = 1$ if $X_i > 0$, and we define $Y_i = 0$ if $X_i \leq 0$. Additionally, we let $\gamma(\phi) = P_{\phi}[Y_i = 1]$.

(i) Find the MLE of $\hat{\gamma}$ of $\gamma$ based on $X_1, ... , X_n$, and write the MLE in terms of the CDF of the standard normal distribution.

(ii) Find an approximate large sample $90$% confidence interval for $\gamma$ based on $X_1, ... , X_n$.

My issues are that I'm having trouble finding the MLE in the first part, and then I'm unsure of how to find the confidence interval for $\gamma$ based on $X_1, ..., X_n$.

I know in general for finding MLEs, you take the joint so you have your likelihood function, $L(\phi, x)$, then maybe if need be you take the log-likelihood function $\mathscr{L}(\phi | x) = ln(L(\phi | x))$, take this derivative with respect to the parameter of interest, and set it equal to zero, then solve for your parameter of interest and make sure to put a little hat on it at the end so you know it's your MLE.

So for this problem in particular, I know what the likelihood function looks like:

$L(\phi | x) = ({\frac{1}{2\pi}})^{-\frac{n}{2}}e^{\frac{-1}{2}\sum_{i = 1}^{n}(x_i - \theta)^2}$ and the log-likelihood function comes out to be $\mathscr{L}(\phi|x) = \frac{n}{2}ln(2\pi) - \frac{1}{2}\Sigma_{i = 1}^{n}x_{i}^{2} + \phi\Sigma_{i = 1}^{n}x_i - \frac{n}{2}\phi^2$.

But from here I don't know what to do. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for taking the time to read and consider my question(s).

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/407344/119261

Comment: The last term of the log-likelihood should be $-\frac{n}{2}\phi^2$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom, thanks for the link!

Comment: Do you mean based the MLE on $Y_1,\ldots,Y_n$ since otherwise it appears like a standard Normal problem.

Comment: @Xi'an, nope, though I guess the person who originally made this problem could have made a typo.

Comment: Then the rule is that the MLE of the transform is the transform of the MLE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a random sample of iid normal RV's the MLE of the $E[X_1]$ is the sample mean. Hence, the MLE of $\hat{\phi}$ is simply the sample mean, $\bar{X}$. Then $$\gamma = P(X>0) = 1-\Phi(0-\phi),$$ 
where $\Phi(\cdot)$ is the standard normal cdf. By invariance of MLE, it follows that the MLE of $\gamma$ is 
$$\hat{\gamma} = 1-\Phi(-\hat{\phi}) =  1-\Phi(-\bar{X}).$$

Denote the 90% confidence interval for $\phi$ as $[\hat{\phi}_{10},\hat{\phi}_{90}].$ It follows that the 90% confidence interval for $\gamma$ is $$[1-\Phi(-\hat{\phi}_{10}),1-\Phi(-\hat{\phi}_{90})].$$